# Spring Boot properties in 'application.yml' not loading from JUnit Test

Tags: java, spring, junit, spring-boot, spring-test

What am I doing wrong? I'm using this little standalone App which runs and finds my `src/main/resources/config/application.yml`. The same configuration doesn't work from JUnit, see below:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
@EnableConfigurationProperties

public class TestApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SpringApplication.run(TestApplication.class);
    }
}


@Component
@ConfigurationProperties

public class Bean{
    ...
}
```

The following doesn't work, the same properties in `application.yml` are not loaded and `Bean` has only `null` values:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = TestApplication.class)

public class SomeTestClass {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Try this:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = TestApplication.class, 
    initializers = ConfigFileApplicationContextInitializer.class)
public class SomeTestClass {
    ...
}
```

**EDIT**:

For Spring Boot version 1.5+, `SpringApplicationConfiguration` was removed in favour of `SpringBootTest` or direct use of `SpringBootContextLoader`.

You can still use `initializers` parameter with `ContextConfiguration` annotation.

Comment: I used \@ContextConfiguration instead of \@SpringApplicationConfiguration and just added the initializers field, and that worked too.  I don't seem to have SpringApplicationConfiguration in my classpath.

Comment: @k-den, you are probably already using Spring Boot 1.5.x, where SpringApplicationConfiguration was removed (it was deprecated since 1.4.x).

Answer (score 38):

The trick to load **any** custom yml file in SpringBoot 2.0 w/o using `@SpringBootTest`

- create some yml file in test\resources
- Use `ConfigFileApplicationContextInitializer` and `spring.config.location` property

Example Code:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(
    classes = { MyConfiguration.class, AnotherDependancy.class },
    initializers = {ConfigFileApplicationContextInitializer.class} )
@TestPropertySource(properties = { "spring.config.location=classpath:myApp-test.yml" })
public class ConfigProviderTest {
    @Autowired
    private MyConfiguration myConfiguration; //this will be filled with myApp-test.yml 

   @Value("${my.config-yml-string}")
   private String someSrting; //will get value from the yml file.

}
```

For JUnit 5 use the `@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)` annotation instead of `@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)`

Comment: But you have to be beware of something... Since you are using a `@ContextConfiguration` that test will actually have a context. So the next test class will have the same context since Spring reuses it between tests, and when executed all at time, your test classes may fail as a side effect. To avoid that behaviour you have to also use `@DirtiesContext` along `@ContextConfiguration`.

Comment: @AngelPinazo, you are correct, this example works for a single test execution in a hello world project, but not useful in the real world.

Comment: For those who want to actually understand more about [@DirtiesContext](https://www.javarticles.com/2016/03/spring-dirtiescontext-annotation-example.html)

Comment: This is more suited for an integration test where you need the application context. Imho a unit test never needs a application context (unless it's a unit test for spring itself). Anyway I was looking for a integration test solution so thanks anyway

Answer (score 10):

Alternative in February 2017:

```
@SpringBootTest
@ContextConfiguration(classes = { TestApplication.class })
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
public class SomeTestClass {
   ...
}
```

the lean variant (withouth `@SpringBootTest`):

```
@ContextConfiguration(classes = { TestApplication.class },
                 initializers = { ConfigFileApplicationContextInitializer.class })
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
public class SomeTestClass {
```

Comment: But @SpringBootTest will not lead you to UNIT-test, but more Integration tests.

Comment: It's true but sometimes I just want to see that the properties are loading.

Comment: `initializers = { ConfigFileApplicationContextInitializer.class }` is what I am looking for! Thanks.

Answer (score 9):

Here's another way: [Spring Boot v1.4.x]

```
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "own")
public class OwnSettings {

    private String name;
    Getter & setters...

}
```

---

```
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@BootstrapWith(SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper.class)
public class OwnSettingsTest {

  @Autowired
  private OwnSettings bean;

  @Test
  public void test() {
    bean.getName();
  }
}
```

**This works ONLY if also 'application.properties' file exists.**

**e.g. maven project:**

src/main/resources/application.properties [ **The file can be empty but it's mandatory!** ]
src/main/resources/application.yml [here's your real config file]

Comment: Thanks a ton! It worked without application.properties in 1.4.3.RELEASE. I only have application.yml under resources.

Comment: You're welcome :-) Ou it's good to know that it works now without 'application.properties'. Thanks for the information.

Comment: What is `SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper.class` please? I don't have it in  `org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:1.5.4.RELEASE`

Comment: Saved my day!! thanks a lot! @DimitriKopriwa you can add it via `    testCompile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-test:${springBootVersion}")
`

Answer (score 9):

**Unit test with Spring Boot 2**

spring boot 2 support 'application.properties' by default,
for 'application.yml' just add below:

```
@TestPropertySource(properties = { "spring.config.location=classpath:application.yml" })
```

e.g.

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@TestPropertySource(properties = { "spring.config.location=classpath:application.yml" })
public class ServiceTest {...}
```

Answer (score 9):

adding to [Liam](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5549569/liam)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55038365/918858), an alternative will be:

```java
@TestPropertySource(locations = { "classpath:application.yaml" })
```

the key difference here is that the test will fail with a file not found exception if `application.yaml` is not in your `/test/resources` directory

Answer (score 7):

Since spring-boot version 2.6.0 `org.springframework.boot.test.context.ConfigFileApplicationContextInitializer` is deprecated and instead is recommended to be used `org.springframework.boot.test.context.ConfigDataApplicationContextInitializer`.

In your tests you can use it as:

```
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {
  ...        
}, initializers = ConfigDataApplicationContextInitializer.class)
public class MyTestingClassIT
```

Comment: Guys, notice Data VS File! Otherwise you will keep search why the class doesn't exist lol

Answer (score 2):

Spring boot 2 example:

```
private final ApplicationContextRunner contextRunner = new ApplicationContextRunner()
        .withInitializer(new ConfigFileApplicationContextInitializer());

@Test public void test() throws Exception {

    this.contextRunner
    .withUserConfiguration(TestApplication.class)
    .run((context) -> {

        .....

    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it helped me, but in current Spring Boot version `ConfigFileApplicationContextInitializer` is deprecated. We can use `ConfigDataApplicationContextInitializer` instead and result will be the same.  So we will have `private final ApplicationContextRunner contextRunner = new ApplicationContextRunner().withInitializer(new ConfigDataApplicationContextInitializer());`.

Answer (score 2):

extending [Liam](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5549569/liam)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55038365/918858)

you can add `spring.config.additional-location=classpath:application-overrides.yaml` property so config from default location will be merged with the additional config provided:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@TestPropertySource(properties = {
  "spring.config.additional-location=classpath:testcases/test-case-properties.yaml",
})
public class SpecificTestCaseIntegrationTest {
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case I was trying to test a library without a `@SpringBootApp` declared in the regular app classpath, but I do have one in my test context. After debugging my way through the Spring Boot initialization process, I discovered that Spring Boot's [YamlPropertySourceLoader](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/cd316e7f3d492201e858c1dd6602a1d4e349f4b2/spring-boot/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/env/YamlPropertySourceLoader.java#L56) (as of 1.5.2.RELEASE) will not load YAML properties unless `org.yaml.snakeyaml.Yaml` is on the classpath. The solution for me was to add snakeyaml as a test dependency in my POM:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.yaml</groupId>
        <artifactId>snakeyaml</artifactId>
        <version>1.19</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

With **JUnit 5** it is also possible to use `@SpringJUnitConfig` which is a composed annotation that combines `@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)` from JUnit Jupiter with `@ContextConfiguration` from the Spring TestContext Framework.

```java
@SpringJUnitConfig(classes = {MyClass.class},  initializers = ConfigDataApplicationContextInitializer.class)
class ApplicationTest {

    @Test
    void contextLoads() {
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ran into the same issue with a unit test in spring boot 3.0.6

My setup was like this:

```java
@SpringBootTest(classes = {MyConfig.class, MyService.class})
class MyServiceTest {
  @Autowired
  MyConfig config;

  @Autowired
  MyService service;

  @Test
  void test() {}
}
```

And I had a config file which was not being read (`src/test/resources/application.yml`)

Turns out that in this case, it was enough to add the `@EnableConfigurationProperties` annotation

Answer (score -5):

This works

```
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner;

@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class ApplicationTest {

    @Test
    public void contextLoads() {
    }

}
```

Comment: This is what I would expect to work, but this doesn't work for me with SpringBoot 1.5+