# Spring boot unit test not work with application.yml

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm not able to make my unit test to read application.yml. I have followed the answer as the url below but it's still not working.

[Spring Boot properties in 'application.yml' not loading from JUnit Test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33213854/spring-boot-properties-in-application-yml-not-loading-from-junit-test#)

Appreciate if somebody can help. Thanks.

My code as below:

Application.java

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ImportResource("classpath:app-config.xml")
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

TestTokenGenerator.java

```
    @RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
    @SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes=Application.class, initializers=ConfigFileApplicationContextInitializer.class)
    @ContextConfiguration(locations={"classpath:app-config-test.xml"})
    public class TestTokenGenerator {

        private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(TestTokenGenerator.class);

        @Value("${test}")
        private String testB;

        @Test
        public void testGenerate() throws UnrecoverableKeyException, KeyStoreException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, CertificateException, IOException{
            log.info(testB);
            log.info(tokenGenerator.generateToken());
}
```

application.yml

```
test: "123123"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the comments for this issue https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/603, for example.

> Declaring both @ContextConfiguration and
>   @SpringApplicationConfiguration directly on a test class is not
>   supported. The first instance of @ContextConfiguration that is
>   discovered for a given test class (either on a class in the test class
>   hierarchy or as a meta-annotation) will be used. All others will be
>   ignored.